# Can not write to MySQL-DB with PHP triggered by JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hello there overflowers!

I´m new to asking on here,
but i´ve been reading a lot on here, which has helped me already.
This time though i am encountering a problem, 
to which i can not seem to find a thread nor a solution.

So the following situation occured:
I have a frontend in which people can change the design to use by clicking on a button.
That does work quite well. But it should save the themename to database.
It says it does, but it does not - if that saving is triggered on the site with JS/JQuery.
It does though, if i trigger it manually with the PHP-file:

*./lib/savetheme.php?user=username&theme=themename*

If i trigger it via JS it goes through the php, which really echoes the needed TRUE.
But it does not save to database. It does not throw any errors (it would die - but it echoes true..).

So here comes the code...

**common.php**

```
<?php 

function m($str) {
    $str = mysql_escape_string($str);
    return "'".$str."'";
}

?>
```

**db-connect-data.php**

```
<?php 

$dbname     = "dbname"; 
$dbuser     = "dbuser"; 
$dbpw       = "dbpw"; 
$dbhost     = "localhost"; 
$dbport     = "3306"; 

?>
```

**db-connect.php**

```
<?php

if (!mysql_connect($dbhost.":".$dbport, $dbuser, $dbpw)) {
    die();
}

if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) {
    die();
}

?>
```

**savetheme.php**

```
require "./common.php";
require "./db-connect-data.php";
require "./db-connect.php";

if(isset($_GET)) {

    $user       = "";
    $theme      = "";

    if($_GET['user'] != "") {
        $user = $_GET['user'];
    }
    if($_GET['theme'] != "") {
        $theme = $_GET['theme'];
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET
            theme   = ".m($theme)."
            WHERE username = ".m($user);

    if(mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "TRUE";
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}

?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("./themes/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $file) {
        $output = str_replace("./themes/", "", $file);
        echo '<button class="buttons themebuttons" id="'
            .$output.'">'.$output.'</button>';
        }
?>
    <div class="ui-widget" id="savethemeok">
        <br>
        <div class="ui-state-green ui-corner-all">
            <p>
                Theme saved successfully!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget" id="savethemeerror">
        <br>
        <div class="ui-state-red ui-corner-all">
            <p>
                Error! Theme could not be saved!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buttons").button();
    $(".themebuttons").click(function() {
            var themename = $(this).attr("id");
            var themepath = "./themes/" + themename + "/jquery-ui.css";
            console.log("Saving new theme...");
            $.get( "./lib/savetheme.php" , {
                user: $("#loggeduser").attr("value"), 
                theme: "'" + themename + "'",
            }, function(status) {
                if(status == "TRUE") {
                    console.log("New theme: " + themename); 
                    $("#theme").attr({href: themepath});
                    $("#savethemeok").show();
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#savethemeok").fadeOut();
                    }, 2500);
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: " + status);
                    $("#savethemeerror").show();
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#savethemeerror").fadeOut();
                    }, 2500);
                }
            }); 
        });
});
```

There is more code, i hope i got all the relevant code out,
but i do not think it will be any more overseeable 
if i copy the almost 1000 lines of code not regarding this particular issue.
If needed i will do though.

I am happy and thankful with any suggestions, as i have already buried some time into that issue and seemingly i do not have any clue as to why it does not save to db when i trigger it via JS but works just fine when manually triggering it with the php...

I am sorry if there is a thread about this somewhere which i have missed out on.
If there is, please let me know. I did not find any though. 
Then again, maybe I´m too stupid to look for it, 
i did struggle a bit with putting my problem in words...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: In your `savetheme.php` file, what is `m($theme)` and `m($user)`?

Comment: function m() comes from common.php - it is just a shortener for mysql_string_escape().


But: I figured the problem. I had some testing running and changed the user in profile. so it just didnt save to the correct user.

so problem already solved by myself. Just being silly...

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using, `mysql_string_escape` has been depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: it is an older version. Im on holiday and using an old xampp for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is fixed.

i had changed the user variable to another user - so naturally it did not save to the user i was looking at.

im sorry to have alerted you.

thanks for viewing into it - and in the honor of Robin Williams: CARPE DIEM.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted in the question, your columns `theme` and `username` appear to be of `varchar` type. Try and modify your query to the following:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET theme   = '".m($theme)."' WHERE username = '".m($user)."'";
```

Comment: I have changed that in my code here.

Thank your for the advice :)